# How to serve static files in ASP.NET 4.8?

Tags: asp.net, static, single-page-application

I'm using regular ASP.NET 4.8 (not .NET Core). I have an api that is served from the url starting from `/api/`. All the front end files are stored in a root level folder called `App`. There is also a `index.html` file, and this is a single page app (SPA).

I am trying to configure this so that if the user requests an api, it goes to the api link. If the user requests a path that points to a file in the `App` folder, it returns that file. Otherwise all other links return the `index.html` file.

I put this in the `web.config` file

```
<system.webServer>
      ....
      <rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="SPA Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                  <!-- match everything by default -->
                  <match url=".*" />
                  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                      <!-- unless its a file -->
                      <!--<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />-->
                      <!-- or a directory -->
                      <!--<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />-->
                      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(App)/" negate="true" />
                      <!-- or is under the /api directory -->
                      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)/" negate="true" />
                      <!-- list other routes or route prefixes here if you need to handle them server side -->
                  </conditions>
                  <!-- rewrite it to /index.html -->
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="App/index.html" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
      ....
</system.webServer>
```

This works fine for the actual `index.html` file being returned. But problem is all the other static files (like js/css), it is just returning the `index.html` file.

How can I resolve this?